# Some items not returned by FoldersApi.GetFolderContents

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

In one of our projects, not all items shown in the BIM360 UI of a folder are returned via the corresponding API-call. We use the Forge .Net SDK:

```cs
var foldersApi = FoldersApi();
var contents = foldersApi.GetFolderContents(projectId, folderId);
```

This results in a list with most of the items that I expect - but without a few `ifc` and `dwg` files (50 are returned correctly, 6 are missing).

The folder I am trying to query is a subfolder of the Plans folder. I have not noticed any differences between the files that work and the ones that are missing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can I know how many items in this folder? It may probably be related, folder contents supports pagination, so the items you expected to see are available in the next page. In addition, I assume you did not specify any filter when get the contents.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang I totally missed pagination! Thanks, solved my issue.

Comment: glad to know it is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget pagination. The Forge .Net SDK has an optional `pageNumber` parameter that defaults to 0.

This is correct:

```cs
var contents = foldersApi.GetFolderContents(projectId, folderId, null, null, null, pageNumber)
```